# Combined uncertainty of two different measurements

Tags: metrology

I am an electrician apprentice in charge of the analytical measurements at the power plant I am hired at.

In certain parts of our process we have redundant pH measurements that feeds into our SCADA system. The measurements are continuous and are not sample based.

I have identified the uncertainty to be +/- 0,10 pH per pH instrument with a confidence level of sigma 2.

Let's say I have three redundant instruments that are freshly calibrated and adjusted and which gives me the following measurements from my process:

- Instrument 1: pH 4,00
- Instrument 2: pH 4,05
- Instrument 3: pH 4,10

The true value, with 95% confidence, then must lie somewhere between:

- Instrument 1: pH 3,90 - 4,10
- Instrument 2: pH 3,95 - 4,15
- Instrument 3: pH 4,00 - 4,20

We of course assume that the process media is homogeneous in it's pH level throughout and that the different pH values arise from the instrumentation itself (for example each pH-sensor reacting differently to changes in temperature, pressure, linearity and so on and so forth)

So now I am suddenly confused and my logical reasoning would make me conclude one of two things:

1. The uncertainty is actually much larger than I thought (3,90 - 4,20) or
2. I can exclude the extremities... and so only the overlapping
   parts of the interval must represent my uncertainty (3,95 - 3,15)
   which however still leaves me with twice the uncertainty compared to
   the uncertainty of each individual instrument (0,20 vs 0,10).

Any ideas on how to tackle this?

By the way, this is a real practical issue I am facing. Even though my pH instruments agrees equally with my reference (buffer solutions) down to 0,00 they still differ slightly between each other when inserted into the process media. Usually up to pH 0,05.

Thanks in advance.

/David

Comment: Have you tried swapping the instruments (i.e. put A to where B was)? If you are using a calibration process and in the calibration solution is exactly the same, then you might have actually different values at the different locations.

Comment: As stated in my question "we of course assume that the process media is homogeneous in it's pH level throughout". I have tried swapping location but the result is the same - it doesn't stem from the media being measured.

These kind of instruments (both sensor and transmitter) do behave slightly differently when wandering outside the otherwise comfy environment of an ion rich buffer solution.

Comment: Since you calibrated the sensors with a uniform reference (excellent!), you may be measuring actual variation in the process. Other possibilities are thermal or electrical effects. Aside from that, I think the theoretical answer for n identical sensors is (sum-of-readings/n), with sigma_combined = sigma_individual/sqrt(n) ...   so you would expect the average reading to be within about +/- 0.1/1.7 ... reality can of course vary

Comment: If I take your 3 measurements 4, 4.05, 4.1, after calculation, I obtain the statistics mean 0f 4.05, with a variance of 1.667x10-6, and standard deviation of 0.041. Does the result mean anything to you?

Comment: @R13 so you are handling the 3 different measurements in terms of precision/repeatability? So does that mean that we first and foremost have an uncertainty based on repeatability and secondly another uncertainty (within the first uncertainty) based on each instruments individual uncertainty (linearity, signal transmission, temperature effects, differences in processing, difference in aging etc)?

Comment: I'm not a statistician but IMO, it is more representative to consider all samples taken throughout the entire system rather than estimating from individual sources. The former eliminates the overlapping inaccuracies of the single source measurements.

Answer (score 1):

You must first calibrate your three devices to give the same result against each other *for at least two different input values*. A one-point calibration only assures that they have no baseline constant offset relative to each other for the given input. Two points assures that the devices are linear in the same way over the calibration range. Three points and further assures that the three devices are calibrated with respect to each other to the $(N - 1)$th order (where $N$ is the number of calibration points used).

It seems you have done this for a certain number of ... perhaps three or so ... buffer solutions. You have assured the accuracy of your devices. You can now incorporate measurement and random uncertainties in your value.

Your devices have reading precisions. This is typically half of the last digit on the digital device. A pH reading of 4.00 on the meter should be reported as $4.000 \pm 0.005$ for example. Let's call this $\delta_{R,pH} = 0.005$, the reading uncertainty to measure pH. You have also obtained specifications for the device uncertainty $\pm 0.10\ (2\sigma)$. Report this as $\delta_{D,pH} = 0.05$ as a $1\sigma$ value. We can combine the reading and device values as variances to obtain a total for the device.

$$ \Delta_{D,pH}^2 = \delta_{R,pH}^2 + \delta_{D,pH}^2 \Rightarrow \Delta_{D,pH} \approx 0.05$$

You take $N_R$ (three) readings at $N_R$ different locations *but presumably having the same representative character* in your system. When you devices are the same (perfectly calibrated), the differences among the $N_R$ readings indicate sampling statistics. In this case, your system is not perfectly mixed or homogenous in its inherent properties (pH or temperature or alkalinity or ...) across the physical locations of the $N_R$ devices.

Suppose that you are interested in presenting a representative statistical value for the *average* of your system over the $N_R$ spatial regions. With the perfectly calibrated devices, you should determine the average $\langle pH \rangle$ and standard uncertainty $S_{pH}$ of your $N_R$ measurements. In your case,  $\langle pH \rangle = 4.05$ and $S_{pH} = 0.05$. We combine the device and random uncertainties as below to obtain an overall uncertainty $\Delta_{pH}$.

$$ \Delta_{T,pH}^2 = \Delta_{D,pH}^2 + S_{pH}^2 \Rightarrow \Delta_{T,pH} \approx 0.071$$

Your final report should indicate that you determined the standard uncertainty not the standard uncertainty of the mean. It should also report the number of measurements taken.

$$ \langle pH \rangle = 4.050 \pm 0.071\ (1\sigma, N = 3)$$

We can debate in a separate thread whether to report two significant digits in the uncertainty versus reporting only one.

You have about a 2% relative uncertainty on the average character of your system, spit evenly between the variation in the sample and the confidence from your measurement devices.

A respectable starting point for mastering this analysis is the [NIST Website on Uncertainties](https://www.nist.gov/itl/sed/topic-areas/measurement-uncertainty). Further reading is found in the Guide to Uncertainties in Measurement (the GUM as referenced on the NIST site).

Comment: You got the upvote just from reading the initial paragraph about the linear response.